# Performance of multiple storyboards (xamarin.ios)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard

I try to create a `xamarin.ios` application.

I created a `storyboard` for all my `views`, but now I have some problems to open it because the size is actually very big.

If I use several `storyboards`, does that have any effect on the performance of the APP?

thx

Comment: You can try to separate it to several as you want(i.e. profileSB, settingsSB). It may use more time on compiling, but won't reduce the performance of app. Moreover if storyboard will reduce the performance why do Apple recommend us creating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use Nib's which is a good practice instead of using multiple storyboard as storyboard may take much longer time to load view and also if you have group of team working on a project it's better to separate views through Nib file and then finally integrate them all.

Regarding performance of application, using storyboard or nib's doesn't matter. But if you are using multiple storyboards you may get navigation issues which you need to look after where navigation controller needs to used and where not.